# Can I use cluster analysis with data that is not independent?

Tags: clustering

I have an experiment in which participants can either make an A-, B- or C-type response. Each participant completes ten trials of the experiment. For each response a participant makes, they will receive a score of 1. After the ten trials, they will receive a score of 10 distributed across the three match types. For example, a participant might have a final score of something like 4 Type-A matches, 5 Type-B matches and 1 Type-C match.

I would like to group the participants by their response profile and then look at differences between them in terms of a different measurement.

Can I use a cluster analysis to group participants by their response profile? I'm uncertain given that the number of type-A matches a participant makes is clearly not independent of the number of type-B and C matches they make.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your analytic, clustering situation is unclear. You have 10 nominal (with possible responses A B C) variables V1 to V10 (ten attempts).  Does it matters that two respondents make the same (or not same) choice in the _same_ variable? Or only the sameness of the _count_ distribution across categories A B C is the basis of respondents similarity?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification query. I’m predicting that individual participants will respond in one or two of the same categories across all of the ten trials (e.g mainly A responses, mainly A&B responses and so on) but the main category/s of response will vary between participants. At the end of the experiment, each participant will have a continuous count score for each type of response. I want to identify groups of participants who respond in similar ways and then investigate differences between these groups in terms of cognitive abilities. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially encode this data as a 3d vector and experiment with different clustering algorithms.

KMeans is sensitive to noise, so it probably won't work well. I'd rather use HAC. Your sample size will likely allow you to analyze the dendrogram.

Also experiment with other distances. Your data can be seen as a histogram or probability distribution, i.e., a user is 30% type A, etc. On such data, other similarities such as Jensen-Shannon divergence may be appropriate.

For best results, experiment with such distances. But also try to find a way to take the **low data resolution** into account. You only have 10 experiments. So someone scoring (2,5,3) may be just a small random deviation away from someone with (3,5,2). But this is very application dependant. You need to find a way of *modeling* a ±0.5 error with each data point.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is only 3D (using A,B, and C scores as the features) you can use something as simple as kmeans, which **doesn't** make any assumptions about the distribution, and will also work fast in your case.

EDIT: I corrected the answer, because I've mistakened kmeans for kNN.

Comment: There is no kNN for clustering. Did you mean to recommend kmeans?